# ServiceNow - define output columns in URL

Tags: servicenow

I am looking for a way (other than view) to define output columns in URL.

E.g.

```
Caller | Assignee| Description | Summary | Other Columns |
```

Is there a way to do so or do I need to have a predefined view, to include it in URL?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it in the main tool yet (Istanbul). A List View would be the easiest way.

However if you are looking for a method to do this for a portal then there is a [Data Table URL Widget](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/build/service-portal/concept/data-table-url-widget.html) for that.

I haven't yet found a way to seamlessly load that widget as a back end include though.